# replace folder separation char for index

Tags: indexing, programming

In index the `!` char is used for item separation.
I have index strings which contain folders and files.

These index entrys should look like

```
\index{files!fonts/!fonts.tex}
```

However I pass these to the index using this command:

```
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{\index{files!#1}}
```

which results in

```
\index{files!fonts/fonts.tex}
```

thus the replacement of every `/` in #1 by `/!` is missing.

How can I replace chars in a string in LaTeX ?

EDIT:

Using the code example from Heiko Oberdiek (which works!) I created the following approach to wrap all items in a `\texttt` command. Unfortunately my approach fails...

```
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{,}[\TempIndexFileEntry]%
  \def\doc@IndexFileEntry\empty
  \def\do##1{%
    \edef\@tempa{\zap@space##1 \@empty}%
    \ifdefempty{\doc@IndexFileEntry}{
      \renewcommand{\doc@IndexFileEntry}{\texttt{\@tempa}}
    }{%
      \renewcommand{\doc@IndexFileEntry}{\doc@IndexFileEntry/\texttt{\@tempa}}
    }%
  }%
  %% Process csv list with command \do (etoolbox)
  \docsvlist{\TempIndexFileEntry}%
  %% rename
  \let\TempIndexFileEntry\doc@IndexFileEntry
  \@bsphack
  \StrSubstitute{\TempIndexFileEntry}{/}{/!}[\IndexFileEntry]%
  \index{files!\IndexFileEntry}%
  \@esphack
}
```

with

```
! Use of \TempIndexFileEntry doesn't match its definition.
\@xs@StrSubstitute@@ ...}\@xs@def \@xs@arg@ii {#2}
\@xs@def \@xs@arg@iii {#3}...
```

Comment: Shoudn't you escape the `!` (usually with `"!`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Package `xstring` provides `\StrSubstitute` that can replace a substring by another
substring:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{/!}[\IndexFileEntry]%
  \index{files!\IndexFileEntry}%
}


\begin{document}
Hello World

\index{files!fonts/!abc.tex}

\labelfile{fonts/xyz.tex}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The file `test.idx` contains:

```
\indexentry{files!fonts/!abc.tex}{1}
\indexentry{files!fonts/!xyz.tex}{1}
```

> [image]

In an more elaborated version of `\labelfile`, the definition could be surrounded
by `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` to preserve the behaviour of `\index` regarding
preceding and following spaces.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \@bsphack
  ...
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother
```

Also some special characters for makeindex can be quoted:

```
\StrSubstitute{...}{@}{"@}
```

Or the file names could be put in `\texttt`, …

Note: Makeindex only supports three levels. Thus the file specification should only
contain one slash. Level 0 is used for `files`, level 1 for the directory and level 2 for the file name.

**Edit**: A further request is indeed to put the file names in `\texttt`.
I start similar as in the edited questions to make a comma separated list, but I use package `kvsetkeys` for parsing the comma separated list, because I am more familiar with this package (as author I should be). We need the following structure of the
index entry, e.g. for `<directory>/<file>`:

```
\index{files!<directory>/@\texttt{<directory>/}!<file>@\texttt{<file>}}
```

Each directory or file is doubled, first it is used as sort key, then it is
formatted using `\texttt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\labelfile}[1]{%
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{/}{/,}[\IndexFileA]%
  \let\IndexFileB\@empty
  \expandafter
  \comma@parse@normalized\expandafter{\IndexFileA}\@AddFileEntry
  \index{files!\IndexFileB}%
}
\newcommand*{\@AddFileEntry}[1]{%
  \ifx\IndexFileB\@empty
    \def\IndexFileB{#1@\texttt{#1}}%
  \else
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\IndexFileB\expandafter{%
      \IndexFileB!%
      #1@\texttt{#1}%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Hello World

\labelfile{README}
\labelfile{fonts/abc.tex}
\labelfile{fonts/xyz.tex}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The `.idx` file:

```
\indexentry{files!README@\texttt  {README}}{1}
\indexentry{files!fonts/@\texttt  {fonts/}!abc.tex@\texttt  {abc.tex}}{1}
\indexentry{files!fonts/@\texttt  {fonts/}!xyz.tex@\texttt  {xyz.tex}}{1}
```

The multiple spaces are an artefact of LaTeX's protection mechanisms and do not
disturb here.

The index looks like:

> [image: Index with file names in \texttt]

Comment: Works as expected. However putting all file names in `\texttt` is a bigger problem than I thought. See my edited question for the approach that I took.

Answer (score 4):

The level character is not fixed if you have a file say `myind.ist` that has the line

```
level ;
```

then `;` would be the level separator rather than `!`.  Any suitable character may be used.

You would then process with

```
makeindex -s myind.ist myfile
```

to use the `myind.ist` style.

See for example the index style designed to go with the `doc` style for documenting latex packages, which is usually installed somewhere like

```
 texmf-dist/makeindex/latex/gind.ist
```